# LINQPad is throwing exception "TruncateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' has no supported translation to SQL" when applying Dump to results

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I have a Linq query done in LINQPad. This query has some froms, joins and a where clause (neither group by nor order by are used).

In where clause I am using below function to remove time from a DateTime field:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(myField)
```

This query return the results into a:

```
IQueryable<MyCustomClass>
```

When I execute query from LINQPad it is executed correctly without errors, but If I perform results.Dump() or results.ToList().Dump() in order to view the results in LINQPad I get below error:

> TruncateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.'

Answer (score 1):

This is not LinqPad specific.

This basically means that the `Where` clause contains some conditions that can not be successfully translated from Linq to SQL.

In order to get around this you can split the where clause:

First part of the where clause contains all the SQL compatible operations, then add a `.ToList()` which will retrieve the data from the database, then finish with the non-SQL, but Linq to Object compatible part of the where clause.

I realize this will cause a greater pull from the database, but that is the limitation.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` will accomplish the same thing but will keep deferred execution (which may not make a difference here but it's worth mentioning as an option)